# Wrong review complaint

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I got this complaint:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13150302
>   Come back tomorrow to continue reviewing.

However, I reviewed "approve" and it was approved. What went wrong here?

Comment: Arno, please see Ed's answer (and feel free to accept his instead of mine) for the root cause of your suspension.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That was me; I banned you manually. Turns out, I was wrong.

I discovered a glitch in the review item display, which I have written about [in this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330549/2057919). I was looking at the item in markdown view and saw only very trivial (and mostly incorrect) edits in the form of inline-code formatting, which Glorfindel discussed in [his excellent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330511/2057919). In markdown view, the major formatting changes were <s>invisible</s> subtle and difficult to see. But that formatting *was* good, and the edit was a good edit. If I had been looking at the rendered version, I would have seen the more significant edits.

Anyway, my apologies for the ban. I have lifted it. Happy reviewing!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I took me a while as well to realize that the edit did have some merit after all. I didn't realize that this could lead to review suspensions :)

Comment: Kudo's for the forthright admission and appropriate response.

Comment: Well the markdown also shows the added new line (which corrects the formatting of the code block), but in a rather unobvious way (with the light green backgroud). Might be worth to think about displaying a little green `↵` icon additionally to the background.

Comment: @Tom Yeah, I am thinking about what to suggest as a feature request. Something like that is probably the way to go. You're correct that the new line is there, but it's not very obvious, and the result (correctly formatting all the code below it) is not at all obvious from the markdown view.

Comment: *(which corrects the formatting of the code block), ..but in a rather unobvious way* Yes, I have almost rejected a few of those myself because it seemed like a trivial change. Unfortunately the view did not really illustrate how drastically that tiny change improved readability.

Comment: @Tom I like that idea.  In the interim it's probably best to toggle any questionable edits between rendered and markdown before swinging a bad edit hammer.  I've seen enough cases where the edit was much clearer in one view than the other that unless it's obvious I normally look at it both ways.

Comment: @DanNeely Yes, switching between these two views should always be done if some formatting has been corrected. First (the rendered side-by-side) to see how it looks and the second one (the markdown view) how it has been done. The third one (inline) can be dropped :D.

Answer (score 11):

This is a manual ban by a ♦ moderator. The problem with the edit is that it introduces the wrong formatting for technical terms like JSCH. `code formatting` should be used for code, not for anything else. Therefore, the edit *could* have been rejected, although to be fair, the edit *did* fix the formatting of the code snippet (which was the *major* problem with the post), so <kbd>Improve edit</kbd> had also been a good action.

<s>I can't tell you whether the ban has been handed out for just this review task, of for a series of similar wrong reviews. Usually, the ♦ moderators are notified when somebody asks for clarification of a review suspension, so they might come here and tell you.</s>

Please check [Ed Cottrell ♦'s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330555/4751173) for the root cause of this issue.

Comment: A manual ban for this edit looks really too much though. It wasn't that bad an edit. There may be more to this story.

Comment: @Tunaki yes, I was already editing the answer to reflect that it might be caused by a series of wrong reviews.

Comment: I don't mind the ban all that much. I was just wondering whether an automatism failed. Therefore, I pulled the atttention to this mishap to help a possible improvement of the automatism. Never mind!