# We need stricter editing reviews

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

Within my answers I have found some edits like changing code brackets style (and only that). In some other case someone had edited my answer changing what the code is doing (and introduced some errors to the code).
In my opinion, there is an urge to increase the number of one's edits. I appreciate the editing itself, but it in some cases it is definitely going too far.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32617585/revisions

Comment: Care to provide some links to these instances?

Comment: The one you linked to only appears to have been edited by you.

Comment: Your "example" of this is a link to a post that nobody but you has ever edited... you corrected *your own* change.

Comment: Shame on me :) Sorry to bother you guys it's definitely not my best day.

Comment: There actually _was_ an edit suggestion in February, but it was Rejected 3 against 2: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11450914 . Even so, many reviewers _are_ too lenient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If one of your posts is edited, you get a notification. That should be a trigger for you to double-check the edit. You can always roll back an edit you don't like, like you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14664795/revisions)*. Also, in the case of a suggested edit, as the author of a post, you have a binding vote to reject suggested edits.

As for the reviews, *suggested* edits are being reviewed but there are a lot of reviewers blindly accepting all non-audit edits. The good news is that ♦ moderators have started to hand out manual bans to these kind of reviewers.

*<sub>: IMHO, the edited version was better, but as the author of the post you have the final say.</sub>

Comment: do you have a source for *"moderators have started to hand out manual bans to these kind of reviewers"*?

Comment: @SamuelLiew No official source, but circumstantial evidence like people opening Meta topics: [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336405/banned-from-reviewing-for-approving-an-approved-edit), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330510/wrong-review-complaint).